# Add reputation to one of the answer of my question

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

How can I add reputation to one of the answer of my question in the math.stackexchange. Thanks

Comment: I am not exactly sure if this is what you want  to do, but if you want to give additional points to somebody that answered your question you can place and award a bounty. To do this just click the link 'start a  bounty' just below the question (yet  **after** the comment section) and follow the instructions. Note though that you cannot do this shortly after having asked the question. You need to wait for, I think, 48 hours.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. Please rewrite it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give additional points to somebody that answered your question you can place and award a bounty. To do this just click the link 'start a  bounty' just below the question (yet  **after** the comment section) and follow the instructions.

Note though that you cannot do this shortly after having asked the question. You need to wait for, I think, 48 hours.

For further information see the relevant section of the Help Center https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty

Comment: Some additional info about bounties can also be found here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info